# Bootstrap 3.1.1 event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm triggering the `shown.bs.modal` event and it does nothing. I had this working before, but now it silently fails. I've completely isolated the problem. For sanity, I removed everything and brought it down to a couple static files and still it doesn't fire. `bootstrap.min.js` is working, jQuery is loaded, and my custom js doc that contains the event is firing(everything but the `shown.bs.modal` of course).

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        function modal() {
            $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                alert( e.relatedTarget.nodeName );
            }); 
        }
        modal();
    });
</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 noPadding">
        <div id="container">
            <div class="width_calculator">
                <a href="javascript:;" data-target="#myModal"><img src="images/catapult.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/catapult.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/catapult.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the bootstrap docs? You need a `data-toggle="modal"` for bootstrap to know to open a modal. The `data-target="#myModal"` is also obviously needed to know *which* modal. Here's an example, and the only thing I changed was adding the `data-toggle` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/zrX9P/ (ignore the broken images, just click the first one)

Comment: I did read it thoroughly. I assumed "data-toggle" wasn't necessary for the JS version and I assumed, inappropriately so, that 'data-toggle' forced the "non-javascript" version of the modal. Sometimes it's the most obvious solution right in front of your nose. :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the JS version", but in the docs, it says: "Activate a modal without writing JavaScript. Set `data-toggle="modal"` on a controller element, like a button, along with a `data-target="#foo"` or `href="#foo"` to target a specific modal to toggle.". Anyways, glad it works now

Comment: you dont need any additional js .. make sure you include the bootstrap.min.js thought

Comment: Ian, that's the part that confused me. You can fire the modal 'without JS' according to the bootstrap documentation. Including "data-target" and "data-toggle" on an elm will invoke the out-of-the-box Bootstrap modal without having to fire the .on() event. Where I went wrong is I thought if I was triggering the modal via the click event, then the "data-toggle" wasn't required. It was obvious that Bootstrap used the "data-target" as a hook replacing the need for an id, but the "toggle" wasn't as obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in response to Jason's comment found here: [Bootstrap 3.1.1 event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271415/bootstrap-3-1-1-event-not-firing#comment37501252_24271415)

You're correct. You can fire the modal without JS. You don't need to use `data-target` or `data-toggle` attributes in this case. The problem you're facing has to do with *how* you are firing this event.

If you take a look at the code you provided, you're using jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function. The description of this method provided by jQuery is **"Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements."** So what you have successfully done is attach a handler that will be called when the `shown.bs.modal` event is fired. That's not exactly what you want, since you actually want to trigger the event; you've just defined what should happen after the event has been triggered.

Taking a look at [Bootstrap's documentation for the usage of modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage), you will notice that you can invoke the modal without the use of the data attributes and instead through the use of JavaScript. To create the modal, simple use the `.modal()` method on your selected modal.

Below is an example of how you would use all of this in your context ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvK9H/2/)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#myImage').click(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal();
        });

    });
</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 noPadding">
        <div id="container">
            <div class="width_calculator">
                <img id="myImage" src="images/catapult.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/catapult.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/catapult.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```